# How can I test the dotenv package to ensure it is hiding sensitive data?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

The [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package is used in Node.js apps to hide sensitive data from the outside world.

Deploying it is simple enough,

```
npm install dotenv
```

Setting up a custom directory inside app.js to access a `.env` file is also straightforward,

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/controllers/.env') });
```

`.env` stores data in a simple name/value pattern,

```
PORT = 5000
PASSWORD = myPassword123
```

From app.js it is easy to access this data,

```
console.log(`Listening on Port ${process.env.PORT}`);
```

**Question:** How do I know any of this is hiding data from the outside world?  What test can I perform with `dotenv` enabled and disabled to show that it is hiding sensitive data?  I'd like to be able to prove it is working.

Comment: `dotenv` does not hide data. It is just an enabler for the environment vairables with intent to use it at different places in the application. Consider it as application level constants container. Thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The dotenv package is used in Node.js apps to hide sensitive data from the outside world.

No it does not. According to the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

> Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env. Storing configuration in the environment separate from code is based on The Twelve-Factor App methodology.

It does not say anything about hiding data.

Comment: Ok I get it.  Upon further research developers are using dotenv and gitignore to keep their private data off github.  dotenv isn't used to hide data during runtime.